# how to convert decimal numbers to array list in sharedPreference in android?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, sharedpreferences

- In my sharedpreference class, I have 30 strings which coming from Edittexts with decimal numbers.
- I want to make an array list containing all of them.
- Then retrieve this array list in an activity and replace it with "*entries*" array list in the code. the output of this array list must be decimal numbers for drawing a chart. Please help to find the procedure.
  Thanks

SharedPreference Class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        //about 30 Strings
        String w1 = prefs.getString("w1", "");
        String w2 = prefs.getString("w2", "");
        String w3 = prefs.getString("w3", "");
        String w4 = prefs.getString("w4", "");
        String w5 = prefs.getString("w5", "");
        String w6 = prefs.getString("w6", "");

        //Convert to decimal numbers here

        //Set up an Array list containing all these numbers here


        }
```

Part of Activity where we want to retrieve array list:

```
private LineData generateLineData() {

    //Call SharedPreferences here
    SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
    Call Array list here



    LineData d = new LineData();

    //Replace or introduce our Array list instead of "entries"
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int index =0 ; index < itemcount; index++)
        entries.add(new Entry(getRandom(15, 10), index));

    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(entries, "first series");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of this with a loop.

```
ArrayList<Double> listOfNumbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++) {
    listOfNumbers.add(Double.parseDouble(prefs.getString("w" + i, "0")));
}
```

This is only going to work if you're sure that all of the values are doubles, otherwise you'll have to check to make sure the `Double.parseDouble` method does not throw `NumberFormatException`

Comment: you just posted this a few seconds before my answer ;-)

Comment: should I use this code without converting strings to double?

Comment: @Civiato You said you wanted to convert the strings to doubles, then add them to an array list containing the numbers. This does that in a single step.

Comment: Thank you. do you have idea about the rest? (how to call it and introduce it as entries array list)

Comment: @Civiato Where is the method `generateLineData()`? If it's in the same Activity/Fragment, then you can just declare `listOfNumbers` in the activity and use it within your method, or create a get method for it.

Comment: No, it is n't. Array list is in a SharedPreference class and I want to open this class in some other activity then call the array list and replace it with "entries" array list in the code.

Comment: @Civiato Does the array list have to be made in the `onCreate()` method? Or could you just put the loop in the `generateLineData()` method instead?

Comment: I didnt understand. There is no loop if array list was made in a sharedpreferences. then I just need to call it and replace it with "entries".

Comment: entries array list must be in generateLineData() method and listOfNumbers in SharedPreferences class in different activity.